# Read user input from piped function

Tags: bash, pipe, file-descriptors, stdin

I want to use a function's piped content as message to an interactive prompt, still from inside the function. Here is what I tried;

```
myfunc ()
{
  local input output
  output=$(cat /dev/stdin)
  
  echo "output: '$output'" >&2
  
  exec 3<&0
  read -u 3 -e -i "$1" -p "Your choice? " input
  exec 3>&-
  echo "input: '$input'" >&2
}
```

I first thought by collecting the piped standard input in a variable would be ok, but it seems `read` doesn't work this way. So I then tried reading from another file descriptor, but it still doesn't behave the way I want.

Isn't `output=$(cat /dev/stdin)` supposed to take all the stdin before moving on with `read`? Is my request even doable? If so what am I missing?

Here is what I hoped to produce:

```
$ echo "1 or 2?" | myfunc 
output: '1 or 2?'
Your choice? 1 or 2
# Edit between 1 and 2
input: '1'
```

Here is what happens:

```
$ echo "1 or 2?" | myfunc 
output: '1 or 2?'
input: ''
```

Comment: The only thing coming from standard input is the string produced by `echo` on the command line. There is no data left for `read` to read. That stream is closed.

Comment: @Kusalananda, can't I somehow make `read` read from another stream, the user input?

Comment: That's what you're doing (although using straight `read` instead of `read -u fd` would be _exactly_ identical to what you use). The issue is that "user input" comes from `echo`.

Comment: In other words, does that mean there is absolutely no way to make `read` work inside a function that already feeds from stdin?

Comment: You could read from two _different_ file descriptors in the function. But in this case, why don't you accept the options string as an argument to the function instead?

Comment: I have functions that generate a command as a string through pipes. If it is satisfying, I could produce it again and pipe it to bash ( ... | bash). I am now trying to make it so that the output string be in the next prompt and modifiable. So that I can modify it directly from prompt and press enter for execution, instead of producing it a second time and piping it to bash, or worse copy-pasting it for modification. So my idea was to pipe it to a function (myfunc) which would read the user input with the stdin string as default value.